# Dayjs locale cannot be set globally

Tags: dayjs

In a react app I want to initialize the dayjs locale globally, but it doesn't works.

In the index.js I have :

```
import "dayjs/locale/fr";
dayjs().locale("fr");
```

But when in any component I log :

```
  console.log(dayjs.locale());
  // this returns 'en'
```

I can't understand why, I checked in my complete code and I never set the locale except in this index.js file.